# How can I render edges?

Tags: rendering

I want to render this creature:

[image]

The problem is that it is made out of edges, is there a way to somehow render these edges?

thanks.

Comment: If you want to make a render of your viewport go to Render-->OpenGL Render Image.

Comment: Which render engine are you going to be using, Cycles or Blender Render?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add a skin modifier which adds geometry to the mesh.

The image below shows two mesh objects one with the modifier visible and the selected mesh has modifier not visible comparison.

[image]

The image belows the skin close to the edges (skinnier).

To achieve this in edit mode use the keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and move the mouse.

[image]

Comment: not really what i want, i want it to render exactly the same like in the pucture